# Import / Export database data with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, import, export

I would like to import / export data using SQL Server Management Studio.
I would like to get the data in the form of queries.
Can it be done ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) - it offers many things, one of them being a [function to generate `INSERT` statements](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=8) from your database tables.

Answer (score 7):

Right click on database -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts...

when you get to "set scripting options", click "Advanced", then "type of data to script", change from "Schema only" to "Schema and Data" or "Data only".