# How to Get the Insert Queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table test. It has some 1000 rows. This table we have developed during testing phase. Now we want those data in the development table. Is possible to get the insert queries?

For example

Table structure is:

```
create table test
(
    id int primary key IDENTITY(1,1),
    name varchar(max)
);
```

and for inserting we did

```
insert into test(name) values('john'),('x')......
```

So now some 1000 rows are inserted.

These were done during testing. Now we want in development. So if is possible to get the inserted queries then I will directly copy and paste otherwise I have to again write 1000 insert queries

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442109/import-export-database-data-with-sql-server-management-studio?rq=1

Comment: @JamesMason I dont want export/import.I just need to insert queries.i dont want store in any other table.

Comment: you want the queries, but you aren't going to run them? Anyway, highest voted answer on that question has what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your table from your Testing phase.

You could use `SQL Import/Export wizard` to get the data over to Dev (with Identity inserts on)

or you could write a SQL query to do that

```
Insert into Dev.schema.Table
Select * from Test.schema.Table
```

I am assuming the schemas are same for both the table in the 2 envs, if not specify column names.

Comment: Thanks foer answering.I want only insert queries

Comment: Could use SQL DMVs, this might help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638435/last-executed-queries-for-a-specific-database

Answer (score 0):

This will help to you

```
INSERT INTO table2
    (column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Please add a brief explanation so OP can learn why this works rather than just copying and pasting :)

Answer (score 0):

create table test_dev(
id int primary key IDENTITY(1,1),
name varchar(max));

insert into test_dev select name from test

-- id values wont be copied over as it is a identity column
-- you can even add where clause in the select query
-- ex insert into test_dev select name from test where id >10

select * from test_dev

Answer (score 0):

to keep your referential integrity for your identity columns

```
create table dev(
id int primary key IDENTITY(1,1),
name varchar(max));

set identity_insert dev on

insert into dev
select id, name
from test

set identity_insert dev off
```

Comment: i dont want to store in any table,I just want to store the insert queries

Answer (score 0):

you can create the scripts yourself using string concatenation, perhaps something like

```
select
    'insert into % values (' + convert(varchar(10),id) + ', ''' + name + ''')'
from test
```

When it comes time to do the insert you need to use the string function replace to replace the % with your new db..table name.